# Way to set HLSL constant

Tags: directx, constants, shader, vertex-shader

Is there any way to set HLSL (for example) vertex shader constant from c++ code in opengl-style?
I mean - no d3dx, no constant-table. Shader is already compiled with fxc.exe and set. Have only LPDIRECT3DVERTEXSHADER9 and LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9. I planned to use `SetVertexShaderConstant`*, but found no way to translate constant name (for example "u_mvpMatrix") to "Register number that will contain the first constant value.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your constants to registers in your shader file. Eg.

```
float4 sample_constant : register(c12);
```

This binds the sample_constant to register 12. You can then use SetVertexShaderConstant() to set the constant using 12 for the register.

Comment: Looks pretty uncomfortable compared to OpenGL =/
In any case - thanks for the reply.

Comment: OK. But actually this is not the answer. More likely you pointed on question's impropriety. This is not what I asked for, but what is needed =)

Answer (score 0):

You can set constants by name using the [ID3DXConstantTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205762(v=vs.85).aspx) API. For example if you have a `float4` constant called `cameraPos` in you shader you can set it from C/C++ like so:

```
float val[4] = {0,1,0,1};
D3DXHANDLE camposHandle = consttab->GetConstantByName(NULL, "cameraPos");
consttab->SetFloatArray(d3ddev, camposHandle, val, 4);
```

In this example, `d3ddev` is the device object and consttab is the `ID3DXConstantTable` object. You can get this object when you compile the shader code using [D3DXCompileShaderFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172732(v=vs.85).aspx) or one of its variants.

Comment: That will work, but key condition was "no d3dx, no constant-table".

Answer (score 0):

With the deprecation of D3DX I feel many people could find this topic in search of a solution to the same problem, as did I.

There is indeed a way to translate constant name to register number, by parsing the actual compiled shader code.

I've found a topic discussing exactly this and positing working code that implements this, and it works flawlessly. I don't want to take credit, but link the original author, so apologies for "just" posting a link to the topic on GameDev.net:

http://www.gamedev.net/topic/648016-replacement-for-id3dxconstanttable/#entry5095598

This solution is exactly what the OP was asking for, not a "workaround".